# Proof by Lewis Carroll that an urn cannot contain two balls

Tags: probability, solution-verification, conditional-probability

I am self-learning probability theory and solving some problems from the book `Probability and Random processes` by Grimmett and Stirzaker. Exercise 1.4.4 poses a nice problem. I would like someone to verify, if my solution is correct and thought process is correct.

> What do you think of the following 'proof' by Lewis Carroll that an urn cannot contain two balls of the same color? Suppose that the urn contains two balls, each of which is either black or white. In the obvious notation $P(BB)=P(BW)=P(WB)=P(WW)=\frac{1}{4}$. We add a black ball, so that $P(BBB)=P(BBW)=P(BWB)=P(BWW)=\frac{1}{4}$. Next, we pick a ball at random, the chance that the ball is black is (using conditional probabilities)

$$1 \cdot \frac{1}{4}+\frac{2}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{4} + \frac{2}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{4}=\frac{2}{3}$$

However, if there is a probability $\frac{2}{3}$ that a ball, chosen randomly from three, is black, then there must be two black and one white, which is to say that originally there was one black and one white ball in the urn.

***Solution.***

I think, the fallacy in this proof has to do with mistaking the unconditional probability $P(BBB)$ for the conditional probabilities $P(BBB|\text{atleast one ball is black})=\frac{1}{4}$.

\begin{align*}
P(\text{Ball drawn at random is black}) = 1\cdot\frac{1}{8} + \frac{3}{8}\cdot\frac{2}{3} + \frac{3}{8}\cdot \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{8}\cdot 0 = \frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}

This makes perfect intuitive sense, because without any knowledge of what ball was added to the urn, the unconditional probability that a ball drawn at random is black is simply $\frac{1}{2}$; the ball is equally likely to be black or white.

Surely, the urn can have two balls of the same color! I'm not sure, how to argue this. But, what I can tell for sure is,

\begin{align*}
P(BBB|\text{atleast one ball is black}) = P(BWW |\text{atleast one ball is black})= \frac{1}{4}
\end{align*}

Comment: What you can tell for sure is wrong.  Given that you've drawn a black ball, the probability that your urn started with two white balls is less than $\frac 14$ and the probability that it started with two black balls is greater than $\frac 14$.

Comment: If you don't add a ball, but accept the rest of the reasoning in the "proof", the chance that the ball you draw is black is $\frac12,$ which "obviously" implies there must be one ball of each color in the urn.

Comment: "if there is a probability 23 that a ball, chosen randomly from three, is black, then there must be two black and one white"  Well this is nonsense.  This language assumes there is one setup of the urn and it is preordained and known.  In actuality there are many possible arrangements and which ones will have different probabilities... This is bait and switch.

Comment: This is equivalent to this problem.  Suppose there are two families each with two children one has two girls, the other has two boys.  If you pick child at random the probability is $\frac 12$ it's a girl.  But the probability is $\frac 12$ then that means that family had to have a boy and a girl.  Do you see the error there?

Comment: @fleablood, thanks for sharing this isomorphic problem, it's clear to me why it shouldn't be true. That's also an abuse of the frequentist view of probability, right? If 1 in 2 on average are girls, the family must have a boy and a girl.

Comment: @RobertShore: is the below computation correct?

Defining 
$WW :=$ the event that the urn starts with $2$ black balls and so forth
$A_B :=$ the event that a black ball is added to the urn.
$R_B := $ the event that a ball drawn at random from the urn is black.

\begin{align*}
P(WW|R_B,A_B) &= P(R_B|WW, A_B) / P(R_B,A_B) \times P(WW|A_B)\\
&= \frac{(1/3)}{(1/3)\times (1/4) + (2/3) \times (1/2) + (1) \times (1/4)} \times \frac{1}{4}\\
&= \frac{(1/3)}{(2/3)} \times (1/4) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{4}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 3):

This is equivalent to this problem.  Suppose there are two families each with two children one has two girls, the other has two boys.  If you pick child at random the probability is $\frac 12$ it's a girl.  But the probability is $\frac 12$ then that means that family had to have a boy and a girl.  Do you see the error there?

There is no "that family".  There are two possible families with different probabilities.  We can't assume a global probability for any possible family will determine anything about the family we eventually pick.  That's bait and switch.

So the urn problem is exactly.  Of the many possible urns we get the probability of drawing a black ball is $\frac 23$.  But that doesn't say anything about the condition of *one* particular urn arrangement which we had no guarentee of being "the" urn.

Comment: 1 - to clarify the mistake is the part 'then there must be two black and one white' ? 2 - i kind of think it's a little similar or related to saying like $a/b=2/3$ implies a=2 and b=3. idk.  is it?

Comment: 'We can't assume a global probability for any possible family will determine anything about the family we eventually pick.' --> ah it's something like restricting the sample space perhaps? probability from picking girl (from Family 1, from Family 2, from Family 1 or 2) = (1or0,1-the previous one,1/2)....or maybe not to do with sample space. or maybe not sample space....i was thinking different probability measures $\mathbb P, \mathbb Q, \mathbb R$...idk.... i couldn't think of a way to bring events here it's not like we have P($A \cup B$)=P(A)+P(B)-P($A \cap B$)...

Comment: I think it's more like saying.  Pick one person at random in New York City.   Write her first name on a piece of paper.  Now count all the number of names you have on paper (one) and the numbers of pieces that have that name (one).  So the probability that your person is named what she is name is $\frac 11=100\%$.  But as she was totally arbitrary it must follow that every New Yorker has the same probability of $100\%$ of having that name.  So every New Yorker has the same name.

Comment: Right thanks fleablood!

Answer (score 2):

Probability of drawing a black ball, after adding a black ball, is $\frac{1}{3} p + \frac{2}{3} q + 1 (1-p-q) = \frac{3-2p-q}{3}$, where $p$ is the probability the urn had no black ball and q the probability it had one black ball at the start. This is equal to $\frac{2}{3}$ for $p = \frac{1-q}{2}$ and $p=0, q=1$ is one of the solutions.

The “proof” in the question has this embedded as an assumption.

The famous Monty Hall problem is in some ways related to this.

Comment: Not sure, if I completely follow. The probability of drawing a black ball, given a black ball was added should be

$P(R_B | A_B) = P(R_B | WW, A_B) \times P(WW|A_B) \\+ P(R_B| WB, A_B) \times P(WB | A_B) \\+ P(R_B| BB, A_B) \times P(BB | A_B) \\
= \frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{4} + \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{2} + 1 \cdot \frac{1}{4} = \frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: My bad, I edited the answer. However, the argument still holds. We do not know the number black balls to start with. All we have are probabilities.